# Object can be parsed from json only

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to specify type in that way, that its generic parameter should be an object that can be parsed from json. So no functions, no dates, no other kinds of values that can't be represented in json. How can I do that?

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQDwBUB8AKEAJwBsAuRAZykJjGQEpyAFQuAWxgtWx0QG8AUImGJC6IkmDoIACwIl6AOigzUYPGIoAHRAF5emrYoBWFBHnr0BAXwEDaUVIWABDCKkRYAnltQBGfiERAA9yKho6AG4bOwcnV3dPH1QAJkCRRFDKalpkaIy0KAANCzCcqJj7MEdnNw9vXwBmdJDyABEXR2jbKpqE+uSAFhbhLMEMjJdyMBA2ACMnAG0AXXyJ4TnyPkQAL3I8cNzEAB9EGeJiehXEazXhW8qXCi9IRFBIWARENhdaCxHEAA3FyERAuPRggDuvygKHQ2GSfnwACIAPTIqwZYGguYQlzQmCwwoI3wpFHo+iIVGoxAAdRc1TBiCcrEIQWE2MQEDxBKJ8IaqEa5IxVJp9MZ4JZcDZWJBiAAJjyYXDMALBsKrNYgA):

```
function get<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json())
}

interface Type1 {
    x: string;
}

interface Type2 {
    x: string;
    getX(): string;
}

interface Type3 {
    x: Date;
}

interface Type4 {
    x: {
        a: number[];
        b: { z: (string | null)[] };
    };
}

async function main() {
    var a = await get<Type1>("/")
    var b = await get<Type2>("/") // Want a error
    var c = await get<Type3>("/") // Want a error
    var d = await get<Type4>("/")
}
```

Comment: Dates actually _can_ be represented in JSON. If you try stringify-ing a date in JavaScript, you'll get a string specifying the information for that Date object

Comment: Also is there any reason to specifically disallow Functions? Stringify-ing an Object that has a Function property will just ignore that property in its JSON representation

Comment: @awarrier99, I'm not going to stringify, I'm parsing. Result of `JSON.parse` does not contain any functions except of those from Object.prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an interface for your desired type that specifies a union of all valid types, like this:

```
interface IJson {
    [key: string]: number | string | boolean | Array<number | string | boolean | IJson | null> | IJson | null;
}
```

**Edit**: After some research, turns out TypeScript actually provides an example of exactly this on their [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html). They recommend this:

```
type Json =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null
    | { [property: string]: Json }
    | Json[];
```

**Edit 2**: Check out my updated (from yours) [sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICkDOB7EyDeAUMicgNoDWEAngFzKZhSgDmAuvSAK4C2ARtGQAfBk1bDkfbNgA2EOHhEBBKFDjUAPBhwgAfBO24J3GTIDchAL6FCcsMgAe9Q3gC8BZHHoAWZNcKgkLCIKC4ATATEpJQ09IzMIOz0AKIOCDJcACYQGgrUADTIAGJcIAhgwEYiACJwkLpWNmDUAA4oWEauUSQi8azdxrwCUAMiUrLyIKPIJjLT+OQtUNhtUM1xYokcyB141qQSu2RsFoQwpeWVeCwQYBoAKsgQDpAgmZhou7oAFFxQMhsEiwAJT0AAKyx4wEwOXu+iIBygtz+eBgtwQAAtfv9gQA6MAYiAgb5IzAtZCufSklq4gBWOm+wOBjQC4Gg8CQyHurQgAEZIgcyEsVtB1qIgds+okLP5mm0uTyAKwUgWkJzi-qynkKtoANhVCLV9ENBxIdA1iQG1n8gXZIR1EAiJscgNYFgONzAAA1Ga7pSzbcFOdy2gBmVUkdW1SAymyBjkoEMQXzO9XOg5eGZDaDHd2mkh8Y3IABe9G+UpYg1MwOOfjzJEsscIcEw1DKyHOZQqRh4cFAjIjyAAbnAoJ4VXAAO59+yeh483k-ABEAHol8yDiOx3wJ9PgLPbvO2mFl2vgcgVyvkAB1BT2OBPVTYEab0fIBC7mfIOdJ0On9cXlet7gOO0DLC+pBbsgmSfvu36Hkmur-sylhAA) that plays around with some of these things. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to pass an interface argument to T unless the interface also has an index signature, something like `{ [key: string]: string }`. You should be able to get around this by changing your interface to a type definition, like `type Type1 = { x: string }` which should then work just fine. I know it's not exactly what you were looking for but I'm not sure that there's currently (or ever will be) support for that in TypeScript.

Comment: Doesn't work. Check your code in the sandbox - it produces an error in all 4 cases (actually it will produce an error for almost any type). https://i.stack.imgur.com/URI5K.png Message: `Type 'Type1' does not satisfy the constraint 'Json'.
  Type 'Type1' is not assignable to type '{ [property: string]: Json; }'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'Type1'.(2344)`

Comment: @Qwertiy ah didn't notice the sandbox. Trying to understand why right now...

Comment: @Qwertiy I can get it to work when declaring a variable with this interface type but not when including it in the function signature. I'll get back to you if I can figure out why

Comment: How can you? `var x: JSON = { a: 4 }` doesn't compile with `Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'JSON'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type 'JSON'.(2322)` too

Comment: @Qwertiy ah I see, in order for it to say that `T extends IJson`, the `T` specified must also have an index signature similar to `[key: string]: ...`. If you change your type interfaces to types, like `type Type1 = { x: string }` it seems to work

Comment: @Qwertiy I'm not getting that issue if I say `let x: IJson = { a: 4 }` where `IJson` is `interface IJson {
    [key: string]: number | string | boolean | Array<IJson> | IJson | null;
}`

Comment: Oops, sorry. I wrote `JSON` instead of `Json`. It really works with variables, but something goes wrong with `extends` clause.

Comment: @Qwertiy yeah so if you supply an interface, then in order for that interface to validly extend IJson, it must also have an index signature in its definition, rather than specifying a single property name. So `type interface Type1 { [key: string]: string }` would work but `type interface Type1 { x: string }` wouldn't. You can get around that by instead specifying a type, such as `type Type1 = { x: string }` which should compile without issues

Comment: I added a second edit to my post addressing some of the issues we ran into

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211222/discussion-between-awarrier99-and-qwertiy).